# How do you calculate pull to par effect on z-spread?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

Currently bonds are widening almost across all maturities and sectors.

I'm looking at some senior bonds with maturities of less than 1 year, that have widened more than 100bps. This happened even though there is a pull to par on the bonds.

How can I calculate the pull to par effect?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about credit spreads ( ie the difference in yield between your bond and some risk free reference bond of the same maturity).   As you approach maturity, both bonds will pull to par but the yield spread does not.  For example let’s say both bonds are 1 yr maturity with 1% coupon.  The risk free bond is already priced at par whereas the risky bond is at 99, implying a 100bp yield spread.  That bond will pull from 99 to 100 over time, but the yield spread can stay at 100.  After 6 months it might be at 99.5 but that half point discount represents 100bp over the remaining 6 months.

Is that what you were asking ?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. That helps a lot and answers my question.
But it made me wonder: what about for Hybrid callable bonds that are fast approaching their next call date? The action on the z-spread 6 months before the next call date is very meaningful.